# I want to append the child categories to parent categories as a json object after using find query

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
I have parent categories and child categories in my database as shown            below.
[{
"name": "electronics"
  , "parent": "/"
  , "category": "/electronics"
}, {
"name": "embedded"
  , "parent": "/electronics"
  , "category": "/electronics/embedded"
},
{
"name": "laptops"
  , "parent": "/electronics"
  , "category": "/electronics/laptops"
},
{
    "name": "dell"
  , "parent": "/electronics/laptops"
  , "category": "/electronics/laptops/dell"
},
{
    "name": "acer"
  , "parent": "/electronics/laptops"
  , "category": "/electronics/laptops/acer"
```

},

```
 {
    "name": "cases"
  , "parent": "/"
  , "category": "/cases"
}, {
"name": "big"
  , "parent": "/cases"
  , "category": "/cases/big"
}, {
"name": "small"
  , "parent": "/cases"
  , "category": "/cases/small"
}]

I want those category to be fetched by appending the child category       with the parent category as json object . ie
[electronics:{
  name:embedded
},
{
name:laptops{
name:dell
},{
name:acer
},
},
cases:{
name:big
},{
name:small
}
]
```

I have fetch the data using regular expression but those data did not came as expected.

I want those categories come in nested json object as shown above.The child category should be append to the respective parent category.

Answer (score 0):

My solution :

```
let newCategory={name:'abc'};
let data = listCategory;
listCategory.push(newCategory);
listCategory.save();
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Can you show me your `fecth data code` ?  I will help you for detail.